# Can a web server shell script use standard input/output to serve multiple requests?

Tags: shell, http

I want to extend [this example](https://debian-administration.org/article/371/A_web_server_in_a_shell_script) webserver shell script to handle multiple requests. Here is the example source:

```
#!/bin/sh
# based on https://debian-administration.org/article/371/A_web_server_in_a_shell_script

base=/srv/content

while /bin/true
do

read request

while /bin/true; do
  read header
  [ "$header" == $'\r' ] && break;
done

url="${request#GET }"
url="${url% HTTP/*}"
filename="$base$url"

if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
  echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r"
  echo -e "Content-Type: `/usr/bin/file -bi \"$filename\"`\r"
  echo -e "\r"
  cat "$filename"
  echo -e "\r"
else
  echo -e "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r"
  echo -e "Content-Type: text/html\r"
  echo -e "\r"
  echo -e "404 Not Found\r"
  echo -e "Not Found
           The requested resource was not found\r"
  echo -e "\r"
fi

done
```

Wrapping the code in a loop is insufficient because the browser doesn't render anything. How can I make this work ?

Application-specific reasons make launching the script *per-request* an unsuitable approach.

---

A TCP listener is required to accept browser connections and connect them to the script. I used `socat` to do this:

```
$ socat EXEC:./webserver TCP4-LISTEN:8080,reuseaddr,fork
```

This gives access to the server by pointing a browser at `http://localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser needs to know how much data to expect, and it won't render anything until 
it gets that data or the connection is closed by the server.

The HTTP response should include a `Content-Length` header or it should use a *chunked
* [Transfer-Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

The [example script](https://debian-administration.org/article/371/A_web_server_in_a_shell_script) does not do that. However, it works because it processes a single request
 and exits which causes the connection to close.

So, one way to solve the problem is to set a `Content-Length` header. Here is an example that works:

```
#!/bin/sh
# stdio webserver based on https://debian-administration.org/article/371/A_web_server_in_a_shell_script

respond_with() {
  echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r"
  echo -e "Content-Type: text/html\r"
  echo -e "Content-Length: ${#1}\r"
  echo -e "\r"
  echo "<pre>${1}</pre>"
  echo -e "\r"
}

respond_not_found() {
  content='<h1>Not Found</h1>
           <p>The requested resource was not found</p>'
  echo -e "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r"
  echo -e "Content-Type: text/html\r"
  echo -e "Content-Length: ${#content}\r"
  echo -e "\r"
  echo "${content}"
  echo -e "\r"
}

base='/var/www'

while /bin/true; do
  read request
  while /bin/true; do
    read header
    [ "$header" == $'\r' ] && break;
  done

  url="${request#GET }"
  url="${url% HTTP/*}"
  filename="$base/$url"

  if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
    respond_with "$(cat $filename)"
  elif [ -d "$filename" ]; then
    respond_with "$(ls -l $filename)"
  else
    respond_not_found
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to make the script trigger the connection close. One way to do this is to send an escape code that `socat` can interpret as EOF.

For example, add a [BELL character code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) (ASCII 7, `\a`) to the end of the response:

```
echo -e '\a'
```

and tell `socat` to interpret it as EOF:

```
$ socat EXEC:./webserver,escape=7 TCP4-LISTEN:8080,reuseaddr,fork
```

Any usually unused character will do, BELL is just an example.

*Although the above will work, HTTP should really contain a content type or transfer encoding header. This alternative method may be useful if using a similar technique to serve arbitrary (non-HTTP) requests from a script.*